# Attribute error in child class for attribute defined in parent __init__ method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following structure:

```
class Flop_helper(): 
    def __init__(...): 
        self.flop1 = [...]

class AnalyseMyHandFlop(Flop_helper): 
    def __init__(...): 
        self.flop1_nums = [card[0] for card in self.flop1]

class AnalyseMyHandTurn(AnalyseMyHandTurn): 
    ....
```

My unit test:

```
@mock.patch('some_path.FlopHelper')
@mock.patch('some_path.AnalyseMyHandOnFlop')
def test_function(mock_AnalyseMyHandOnFlop, mockFlopHelper):
    amhot = AnalyseMyHandOnTurn(...)
```

When I run the above test, I get:

```
self.flop1_nums = [card[0] for card in self.flop1]
E       AttributeError: 'AnalyseMyHandOnTurn' object has no attribute 'flop1'
```

The error message is so extremely confusing to me for two reasons:

1. `AnalyseMyHandOnTurn` doesn't have an attribute `flop1`??? But I guess since we are inheriting `AnalyseMyHandFlop`, I can see why this could be.
2. Didn't I mock out `AnalyseMyHandFlop`? So I would expect all its attributes and everything related to its class to be mocked out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inherit a class in Python you get all its attributes methods etc.
you also inherited the `__init__` method, but when you defined the `AnalyseMyHandFlop` class you also provided an `__init__` method overriding the one in `Flop_helper`, so when creating a new instance of `AnalyseMyHandFlop` only the `__init__` of `AnalyseMyHandFlop` is being called.

to fix it you need also to call the `__init__` method of the parent class (`Flop_helper`) you can do that by adding this line to your code:

```py
class AnalyseMyHandFlop(Flop_helper):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # new line
        self.flop1_nums = [card[0] for card in self.flop1]
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you, very clear explanation. 

Just to clarify my understanding - by using super as you have done above, we are NOT overriding the __init__ method in the parent class Flop_helper?

Comment: And rather than having super(), can I do something like: Flop_helper.__init__(). 
Is that the equivalent?

Comment: No problem, we are not overriding the init method, I recommend you to read about python super, just search in Google `super python` or similar it will be better than any explanation I can provide.